# Getting value of first intent sum into the second

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having trouble with coding a BMI calculator.

I want to show in the second activity just the value already calculated, but the value is calculated only when I press the button and then going directly to the second activity with no value.

Thanks

> Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        final EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        final TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);


        Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resultado.class);
                i.putExtra("result1", tv4.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);

                String str1 = e1.getText().toString();
                String str2 = e2.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str1)) {
                    e1.setError("Insira o peso em Kg");
                    e1.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str2)) {
                    e2.setError("Insira a altura em Cm");
                    e2.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                //Get the user values from the widget reference
                float weight = Float.parseFloat(str1);
                float height = Float.parseFloat(str2) / 100;


                float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);


                String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);
                tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bmiValue));


            }
        });

    }

    //Calculate BMI
    private float calculateBMI(float weight, float height) {
        return (weight / (height * height));
    }
```

> Second Viewer

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);

        final TextView imc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imc);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String result1 = i.getStringExtra("result1");
        imc.setText("Your name is: " + result1);

        Button back = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Button Listener please call start activity after calculations.

```
Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        String str1 = e1.getText().toString();
        String str2 = e2.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str1)) {
            e1.setError("Insira o peso em Kg");
            e1.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str2)) {
            e2.setError("Insira a altura em Cm");
            e2.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        //Get the user values from the widget reference
        float weight = Float.parseFloat(str1);
        float height = Float.parseFloat(str2) / 100;


        float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);


        String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);
        tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bmiValue));


        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resultado.class);
        i.putExtra("result1", tv4.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

start your activity after doing all calculations.

```
String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);
tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bmiValue));

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resultado.class);
i.putExtra("result1", tv4.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```